# Connecting to MySQL - one client connection returns IP. The other clients return hostname

Tags: mysql

I have 4 servers that connect to a MySQL database.  DB server running Ubuntu 12.04
client-server-1.mydomain.com 1.2.3.1  Ubuntu 14.04
client-server-2.mydomain.com 1.2.3.2  Ubuntu 14.04
etc...

When connecting, one of the 4 returns the IP address of the client rather than the hostname.

For example:

From client-server-1 it returns the IP when trying to connect
`$ mysql -umyuser -pmypass -hdb-server-1.mydomain.com -Dmydatabase`
**Access denied for user 'myuser'@'1.2.3.1'**

From client-server-2, it returns the hostname
`$ mysql -umyuser -pmypass -hdb-server-1.mydomain.com -Dmydatabase`
**Access denied for user 'myuser'@'client-server-2.mydomain.com'**

I understand MySQL does a reverse DNS lookup, and I did verify that the PTR record returns correctly on the MySQL server for client-server-1.mydomain.com. (and everywhere else I've checked)

`$ dig -x 1.2.3.1`
**client-server-1.mydomain.com**

I'm not concerned with the grants at this point as I have yet to set them up for this user. I'm just curious about why 1 out of 4 returns the IP instead of hostname when trying to connect to MySQL